# Clear or remove all chart on zedgraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

How can I clear the chart of zedGraph?
`z1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();` command only clear the curve alone. I want to clear entire graph and replace with new chart line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have gotten the answer by now, but for others who are interested in this topic, here is what I do in my own code, I have a clear method that has the following calls that clear my chart,

```
  z1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
  z1.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Clear();
  z1.GraphPane.Title.Text = "";
  z1.GraphPane.XAxis.Title = "";
  z1.GraphPane.YAxis.Title = "";
  z1.GraphPane.Y2Axis.Title = "";
  z1.GraphPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Linear;
  z1.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = null;
  z1.RestoreScale(z1.GraphPane);
  z1.AxisChange();
  z1.Invalidate();
```